# ERROR in ImportTsv-HBASE BULK LOAD

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have hbase 0.94.0. I tried doing bulk import using the importtsv tool.
Here is the command i gave

```
./hadoop jar /home/ericsson/Desktop/ProjectFiles/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,a,b,c,d,e,f,g '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' Test1 /home/ericsson/Desktop/ProjectFiles/inputFiles1/CharginUsage-m-00000
```

Test1-My table that already exists in Hbase.
/home/ericsson/Desktop/ProjectFiles/inputFiles1/CharginUsage-m-00000- My directory where i have the CSV file.

I got the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multimap
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 3):

importtsv task needs Google's Guava library in order run.   This library is present under **$HBASE_HOME/lib/guava-.jar**
It is matter of telling hadoop to fetch this guava jar during execution.  Simply you could copy the jar from hbase lib to hadoop lib.  A more decent solution is to add this jar path to hadoop classpath or execute the hadoop task with the below command.

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_HOME/lib/guava-<version>.jar`

OR

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`` `hbase classpath `` ` /hadoop jar /home/ericsson/Desktop/ProjectFiles/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,a,b,c,d,e,f,g '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' Test1 /home/ericsson/Desktop/ProjectFiles/inputFiles1/CharginUsage-m-00000*